# Licensing requirements (Boost, Qt Creator)

Tags: boost, licensing, qt-creator

I'm a little confused by exactly what the rules are for using licensed libraries/software. I've produced a small C++ program in Qt Creator using the Boost libraries and the MSVC 10 compiler. I have no intention of selling this software but I may well put it up on the internet at some point. Does this mean that I have to license it under Boost license and LGPL (due to Qt Creator) or is this not needed? I have little adversion to doing so but would like to understand the rules better and haven't been able to find a plain English "can and can't do" with Google or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Qt Creator** is licensed under LGPL. So, if you use dynamic linking, you don't have to worry about Qt.

You have no problem if you...

- use the original qt libraries,
- distribute the `dll` files with your application,
- you **do not** compile those `dll` files into your `exe` file.

Please check this question: [Qt, LGPL, Commercial closed-source application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024547/qt-lgpl-commercial-closed-source-application?rq=1)

---

**Boost** has its own license named Boost License.

From Boost web site:

> if you distribute your own code along with some Boost code, **the Boost
>   license applies only to the Boost code (and modified versions
>   thereof)**; you are free to license your own code under any terms you
>   like.

From Boost License:

> The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement,
>   including the above license grant, this restriction and the following
>   disclaimer, must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole
>   or in part, and all derivative works of the Software, **unless such
>   copies or derivative works are solely in the form of
>   machine-executable object code generated by a source language
>   processor.**

Which means that if you did not made any changes in original Boost Library you **only** need to have Boost License file in your **source** code. This is your only restriction.

---

About **Visual C++** please check here:
[Visual Studio Express 2010 license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624589/visual-studio-express-2010-license)

Comment: Do Qt and Qt Creator have the same license?